# How to model a practical zener diode in forward bias

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, analog, zener

In circuit (below) ,a practical zener diode (which is modeled as series zener diode and a resistor as given in question ) and other elements as shown in figure.[image]

I am solving this circuit to calculate current  due to ac source at different conditions

I calculated current in two conditions

1.when zener diode act as   open circuit (in reverse bias)

2.when zener diode act as a ideal voltage source with resistance in series(in reverse bias)

But I'm confused in 3rd condition i.e when zener diode is in forward bias as we know in forward bias zener diode behave like a normal diode(considering ideal condition) and we can replace it by an ideal diode but

what about resistance of zener diode ? Should I remove it in forward bias conditions or not?

Comment: This [may help](http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/312/handouts/Zener%20Diode%20Models.pdf).

Comment: I think the answer to your question is dependent on the how the specific person who wrote the problem wants you to model the zener.  I suppose three possibilities are that the dynamic resistance is (1) the same in both conduction regions, (2) you assume it's zero in forward region since it's not written on the board, (3) it's some other value in forward region and they just forgot to write it on the board.